# flushing output from child process or reopening after .end

Tags: node.js, pipe, child-process, spawn

I am using `child_process` spawn to create a process and piping input to its stdin.
However, I don't get any `.on('data', ...` event until I do a

```
child.stdin.end()
```

But this will close the pipe for further input.

```
unhandledRejection Error: write after end
```

So is there a way to either

- force data to get flushed to stdout
- reopen a child for pipe to stdin after `stdin.end` has been called?

other github notes + code is here
https://github.com/callemall/fasttext-js/issues/4

Comment: So it's the child process that's not flushing its output?

Answer (score 1):

this was my problem I needed to terminate each input with a `\n` 
doh!